# unable to move second view controller without using segue in swift

Tags: swift2

I have written following code to move from one view controller to another. But that **code** doesn't work in my project

```
let PayMoney_NetBankingView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PayMoney_NetBankingStoryId") as! PayMoney_NetBanking

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(PayMoney_NetBankingView, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate a view controller from a storyboard the hosting navigation controller is not instantiated with it. This means the navigationController is nil.

You should add an identifier to the navigation controller and instantiate that and get the view controller using the `viewControllers` property of the navigation controller.